# Determine status of an Azure SQL Data Warehouse via REST api

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

as the title says, I would like to determine if my DW is paused/running via the REST api.

I am currently trying to make a get request as shown below, but the response I get gives **"status": "online"** as soon as the DW is beginning to resume. The portal says "Resuming..." but the status should probably be "paused" until its done resuming.

If you're wondering the context of why I'm asking this, I want to make sure the DW is on before turning on a streaming analytics job. This is all being automated.

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + SUBSCRIPTION_ID + "/resourceGroups/" + RESOURCE_GROUP + "/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/" + SERVER_NAME + "/databases/MyDW/?api-version=2014-04-01");

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        Trace.WriteLine("responseString for DW get: " + responseString);
```

Comment: Hey Jaked222,

I just reran the following scenario as you suggested:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayCZf.png

and the status I receive is also resuming from the REST API. Are you referring to the status in sys.databases?

Answer (score 2):

You can determine whether the status of the system is online with whether the status returns *Online* or not. During a resuming state, the status returned by the Get Database API **should** return *Resuming*

[image: Resuming]

Currently sys.databases DMV returns *Online* regardless of the db state. REST API should be accurate.